# converting image to pdf using fpdf library reduces clarity of pdf content

Tags: fpdf

I have trying to convert image to pdf using mpdf library,everything works well but the clarity of content is missing in pdf generated.The image i have been trying will have dynamic width and height.If i fixed width and height,then some of the pdf's content are expanding ,some are missing content.

```
        $pdf = new FPDF();
        $pdf->AddPage();
        $pdf->Image('uploads/'.$imagefile_name,10,10,200,250);
        $pdf->Output('F', 'uploads/' . $file_name, true);
```

I have tried different codes,can anyone help me so that width and height is set dynamically without missing clarity

[image]

Comment: Use the PHP `getimagesize` function to determine the dimensions of your image and adjust the call to `$pdf->Image` as needed.

Comment: @Dave yes i have tried with getimagesize ,but not working,complete pdf is not coming.Please check my edited question for  image i get  when getimagesize used